# How to make the text changeable when listbox is binded through a ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am developing a window phone app. In which I have a list box and the view of the template has a field with time.
I have binded a n observable collection to the list. My problem is the time that I have binded to the template should be changing with timer tick. I have to show all as timer running.
How can I perform this when the it is binded through observable collection.

How could i make it change every sec. Will making the observable collection notify every second is a good idea. Or any idea one could provide will be a good advise for me.

Comment: ObservableCollection will update only when item is added/removed. You will need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged. I think there was also something like *TrulyObservableCollection* - I also think that there are many tutorials/blogs/SO questions regarding this

Answer (score 0):

Try this

XAML:

```
        <ListBox x:Name="lstData">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Data1}" Margin="20"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Data2}" Margin="20"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Data3}" Margin="20"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

cs:

```
ObservableCollection<Data> obs = new ObservableCollection<Data>();
        void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            obs.Add(new Data("Start", "Time :", "0"));
            lstData.ItemsSource = obs;
            LoadTimer();
        }

        public void LoadTimer()
        {
            int sec = 0;
            Timer timer = new Timer((obj) =>
            {
                Dispatcher pageDispatcher = obj as Dispatcher;

                pageDispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                {
                    sec++;
                    obs[0] = new Data("Changing", "Time :", sec.ToString());
                });

            }, this.Dispatcher, 1000, 1000);
        }

        public class Data
        {
            public string Data1 { get; set; }
            public string Data2 { get; set; }
            public string Data3 { get; set; }

            public Data() { }

            public Data(string Data1, string Data2, string Data3)
            {
                this.Data1 = Data1;
                this.Data2 = Data2;
                this.Data3 = Data3;
            }
        }
```